# Jackson (jersey) deserialize exception - (for id type 'Id.class'): no such class found

Tags: rest, serialization, jersey, osgi, jackson

I have a REST web application based on Jersey and running in an OSGi container - Geronimo3. The service is returning results fine with Json POST data and able to marshal json output to java object. I have written a REST client and that too works fine with main method getting back the response object.

However, Rest client fails in one scenario - when called from Bundle Activator class in a OSGi web application. It gives below error in this case.
Also when the web application is fully initialized, the Rest client works fine in request scope. I am suspecting some issue with classloaders since OSGi classloading is different regular webapps (tomcat). Also the response class uses @JsonTypeInfo annotation to map Interface type to concrete class.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type id     'com.nnn.IContentValue$ContentText' (for id type 'Id.class'): no such class found
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:57)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:113)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:82)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:52)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBind(MapDeserializer.java:321)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:249)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:33)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround that I'm documenting.

It is caused due to org.codehaus.jackson.map.util.ClassUtil.findClass loading typeid class from org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder that is different from OSGi bundle classloader during bundle init phase.

I replaced the contextClassLoader using Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()) before making the jersey client call and reverting it to original one in finally block.